# ¿Como usar variables dentro del app.confg?

Tags: c#

El siguiente código es lo que pretendo hacer en mi `app.confg`. He leído varios post referentes a este tema pero no he logrado mi objetivo. Si alguien podría indicarme la solución para resolver esta situación.

```
<configuration>
  <appSetting>
    <add key="name" value="Peter"/>
    <add key="lastname" value="Parker"/>
    <add key="fullname" value="{name}.{lastname}"/>
  </appSetting>
</configuration>
```

Cuando obtengo el valor de `fullname` en el codigo usando `ConfigurationManager.AppSetrings["fullname"].ToString()` me devuelve `"{name}.{lastname}"` y yo busco obtener `"Peter.Parker"`.

Gracias de antemano.
Editando:
Puse el ejemplo anterior para mostrar un ejemplo más sencillo pero lo que realmente quiero hacer es esto:

```
    <configuration>
      <appSetting>
        <add key="user" value="root"/>
        <add key="pass" value="root"/>
      </appSetting>
      <connectionStrings>
         <add name="mysql" connectionString="datasource=localhost; port=3306; username={user}; password={pass};" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
        </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

Y luego en el código a partir de `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ConnectionString` obtener `"datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=root;"`
Discúlpenme por no poner mi objetivo desde el principio. Saludos

Comment: He editado la pregunta para añadir el resultado que supongo que esperas, si no he atinado con el valor, te invito a editarla de nuevo para que quede claro ese punto. Un saludo.

Comment: No puede combinar appSettings como así.  Tiene que obtener los pedazos y hacer lo que quiere en su código.

Comment: No te acomoda manejar el valor del fullname concatenando *name* y *lastname*? No estoy seguro si puedes usar concatenaciones en el `App.config` =/

Comment: No entiendo porqué hacer eso si puedes poner el nombre y apellido tal cual? Cuestión de cortar y pegar. Que sepa no puedes referenciar a otras variables salvo que implementes tu propia clase de configuración que lo haga. En todo caso has la concatenación  del fullname en el codigo.

Comment: Mi objetivo es realmente insertar las variables dentro de la declaración de un connectionString lo que puse un ejemplo más sencillo que utiliza la misma mecánica voy a editar la pregunta para mostrar lo que realmente necesito

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AppSettings` no soporta templates por lo que tendras que cargarlo segun el key que buscas. Si buscas es el nombre entonces tendras que buscar por el key `name`:

```
String name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"];
```

Ahora bien, **si en serio necesitas eso**, puedes crear un metodo que si acepte templates y puedas cargar el valor segun el usuario lo pide:

```
String Settings(String key)
{
  var name = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"];
  var lastName= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["lastname"];
  return key.Replace("{name}", name).Replace("{lastname}", lastName);
}
```

Uso:

```
string fullName = Settings("{name} {lastaname}"); // Peter Parker;
string fullName = Settings("{name}/{lastaname}"); // Peter/Parker;
```

Nota que esto no es eficiente en nada y no le veo ninguna necesidad de hacerlo asi. Solo lo agrege para darte una idea de lo que puedes hacer.

Comment: He editado mi pregunta gracias por la respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Es que funciona bien así como esta.

En appSetting del web config guardas las keys y sus values (solo strings), después las llamas tal como lo estás haciendo.

En tu caso deberías concatenarlas desde tú código para obtener ese resultado:

```
string fullname = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["name"].ToString() + "." + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["lastname"].ToString();
```

Para connection Strings así:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mysql" connectionString="datasource=localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=root;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Desde el código la obtenés así:

```
string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mysql"].ToString();
```

Saludos!

Comment: Si gracias por la ayuda he editado mi pregunta para mostrar mi verdadero objetivo.

Comment: De nada, ahí te puse un ejemplo para el connection string, espero que te sirva, saludos

Comment: Mi objetivo es usar las variables user y pass dentro de la declaración  del connectionsString